# nginx 301 from www to mobile site causes 404

Tags: mobile, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm getting a 404 for the root of my mobile site.  My browser detection code looks for a mobile user-aget, sets the vary header, and 301s to the mobile site.

Here is the main site config

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.mydomain.com;
  location / {
    if ( $is_mobile) {
      add_header Vary "User-Agent";
      return 301 $scheme://m.mydomain.com$request_uri;  
    }
}
```

Here is the mobile site config

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name m.mydomain.com;
  root /var/www/mobile;
  index index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @dynamic;
  }

  location @dynamic {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.html last;
   }      
}
```

I'm using the FireFox Override User Agent extension to test.  If I go to www.mydomain.com the app loads properly. However, when I switch to a mobile browser Nginx 404s.

Nginx 200s for pages entered manually -

```
http://m.mydomain.com/index.html
http://m.mydomain.com/about.html
http://m.mydomain.com/pricing.html
```

Since both index and root are set shouldn't the site point http://m.mydomain.com/ to http://m.mydomain.com/index.html?

If not what is the best standardized approach to get this working?

**UPDATE:** Added config for mobile detection

Here is the config I use in the main nginx.conf file for mobile detection

```
map $http_user_agent $is_desktop {
default 0;
        ~*linux.*android|windows\s+(?:ce|phone) 0; # exceptions to the rule
        ~*spider|crawl|slurp|bot 1; # bots
        ~*windows|linux|os\s+x\s*[\d\._]+|solaris|bsd 1; # OSes
}


map $is_desktop $is_mobile {
        1 0;
        0 1;
}
```

Comment: Post how you set $is_mobile and I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

See nothing wrong. I tried your config file in my devbox and it worked: the request was redirected to m.mydomain.com and the index.html was served.

So it could be something else caused the issue. How did you set $is_mobile? Maybe setting $is_mobile has some side effect and that if block in your question is not picked by nginx to serve the mobile request. Your mobile request went into another location block that doesn't know how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

In sites-available there was a file named 1 which was symlinked to site-enabled.  Not sure how it got there but I unlinked and deleted it, restarted Nginx, and / now resolves to index.html properly. Very odd.

Comment: what's the content of that file? It might have the server block that conflicts with your www.mydomain.com server block, and nginx may never use the one you list here.

Comment: Oddly enough its was a previous version of my site file that used different browser detection logic.  Also, I was disregarding the duplicate hostname message when I reloaded Nginx. *sigh* On Android this was causing an infinite loop in the browser :(